# In Numerical Relativity (Neutron Star Mergers for example), the Metric is constantly changing. What does the "time" in each frame measure?

Tags: general-relativity, simulations, magnetohydrodynamics

Hi there and really sorry for bothering you!

Recently I have begin to studing GR and I have found some simulations regarding Neutron Star Mergers.

Take a look at this video for example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UQCfo5L3ShQ&ab_channel=CoRe-ComputationalRelativity

If the metric is constantly changing. What exactly does the "time" in video measures? An observer at inf? I really dont get it.

Ty in advance and sorry for the "silly" question.

Comment: Looking through the reference under the video (https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.11161) its "simulation" time meaning in their case probably the time parameter in the Arnowitt-Deser-Misner (ADM) equations (i could be wrong since I am no expert in numerical GR and I have not looked into this specific simulation in detail). The ADM eqs. are a reformulation of Einsteins equation for the time evolution of spatial hyper-surfaces (usually encoded by the evolution of a 3d spatial metric, an extrinsic curvature, lapse and a shift vector).

Comment: @N0va Is this maybe somehow related to 3+1 GR Formalism? Sorry just looked up into ADM and this reference and couldnt find much. Sorry i'm not good enough as u can see. Will look it more later and add to this :)

Comment: Yes the ADM equations are based on the "3+1 decomposition". As a free resource to get started I can recommend this lecturenotes: https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0703035 As for textbooks: T. W. Baumgarte and S. L. Shapiro, Numerical Relativity - Solving Einstein’s Equations on the Computer and M. Alcubierre, Introduction to 3+1 numerical relativity would be two.

Comment: Hey! I have read Gourgoulhon's book :) That's the only book I have read tbh along with some other more simple, about GR. I tried to find that "time parameter in the Arnowitt-Deser-Misner (ADM) " you were referring before  but didn't see any. Will check again the whole chapter because it has been a year before I read it.

Comment: @N0va This time parameter is not in match with an observer from Infinity right?

Comment: I am not 100% sure but I do not think that the "Simulation"-time they refer to in the paper is the time of an observer at Infinity.

Comment: @N0va Hi there! I studied that Gourgoulhon's Book. If you care that time parameter is connected to any coordinate system 's time through the relationship: $d\tau = N dt$ so since $N=1$ for inf, the time parameter is equal to an observer like us.

Comment: @N0va still I have one more question if you care to somehow go to DM or so